# How to match and compare two timestamp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

## The problem

I have a strange situation : I'm using firebase as DB and JS/Angular to develop my app. I'm facing this situation where I need the client check if an event's date is reached, and if it is, delete this event from the server.

I guess the problem does not come from the trigger, but from my timestamps manipulations.

From now, I'm using this to fill up the end date :

```js
// The date format of x is : 2017-06-08T16:10
    var x = document.getElementById("dateEvent").value;
    $scope.endDate = new Date(x).getTime();
```

```html
<label class="item item-select item-input item-light"><input type="datetime-local" id="dateEvent"></label>
```

## Tests

And to test if the end date is reached, I 'm using this method :

```js
// Moment.now() and endDate are timestamps, endDate comes from the HTML input
    
    if(moment.now() > endDate)
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
    
    
// Also tried to get a timestamp from the Firebase server but before using it, it is necessary to store it, so this doesn't work...

 var timeServ = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

    if(timeServ > endDate)
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
```

The point is, this (the first solution with moment.now() ) is working, but for some reason if nobody (clients) is connected at the right time my event remain in the DB and become "immortal".

An other strange thing, is I'm using timestamp that are really big, for exemple these two : 1496926321039 and 1496933687000. I'm not sure it's something normal because when I'm trying to use an online translator to check "**timestamp-> to -> date**" it gives me an impossible date...

## EDIT :

Mmh...I find the problem. When i'm testing the app on my laptop it works, but from my iphone 2 hours are added on the endDate, of course the timestamp couldn't be correct.

So now, i'm trying to figure out how can i convert a UTC date into timestamp, without using `new Date(x).getTime();`. Do you know a JS or Angular function that can handle that ?

Comment: Time stamps in JavaScript are millisecond time stamps. Most other languages use seconds. Divide by `1000` to get the time stamp in seconds.

Comment: OK, so now I know why I wasn't able to use an online translator. But, is that could make the comparison wrong ?

Comment: Check the values of `moment.now()` and `endDate`.

Comment: You should be consistent with the APIs you're using. If you are using moment, use moment. Parse the "dateEvent" value to a moment, then use `moment.isAfter()`/`moment.isBefore()` to check. Comparing a moment object with a Date object using `<`/`>` is not what someone would want to do

Comment: Thank you, you made my day ! Indeed, it was wiser to stay with my API. Instead of manipulate timestamps, i parsed everything into UTC dates and used `.isAfter()` to compare values. Thanks again ;)